# Where to call the Update chat message "delivered" function when app is on Background in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, chat

Im trying to implement the whatsapp like functionality of message being delivered when the receiver's app is in background state and the wifi is on.

I want to call the function to update the message document status from 'sent' to 'delivered'. But cant find where to call it from. I tried calling it inside FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen but it is still not working on background.

```
static setDeliveredStatus(
          {required String senderId,
          required String receiverId,
          required String receiverName}) async {
        print('setting = ${receiverName + receiverId}');
        print('${currentUser!.displayName!} + ${senderId}');
        QuerySnapshot query = await _firestore
            .collection(CollectionKeys.messages)
            .doc(receiverName + receiverId)
            .collection(currentUser!.displayName! + senderId)
            .where('status', isEqualTo: describeEnum(MessageStatus.sent))
            .get();
        query.docs.forEach((doc) async {
          await doc.reference
              .update({'status': describeEnum(MessageStatus.delivered)});
        });
      }
```

This above function is currently being called inside initState of my home.dart screen in a onMessage Listener:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      if (message.notification != null) {
        LocalNotificationService.createAndDisplayNotificationChannel(message);
        FirebaseServices.setDeliveredStatus(
            senderId: message.data['senderId'],
            receiverId: message.data['receiverId'],
            receiverName: message.data['receiverName']);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FCM SDK has an `onBackgroundMessage` function where you can configure a callback function when receiving messages while the app is in the background.

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_onBackgroundHandler);
```

See this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#apple_platforms_and_android) for reference. In the call back method you could put the logic to update the document.